# How to sign a data with PFX-certificate with PHP?

Tags: php, certificate, sign, pfx

I have a certificate 'cert.pfx' with a password 'passkey'.
How can I sign some data with this certificate?

Comment: $cert_store = file_get_contents('cert.pfx');
openssl_pkcs12_read($cert_store, $cert_info, 'passkey');
It works ok. I can read the cert data. But have not idea how to sign another data with it.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620088/1461181