# Sign a XML file with .pfx certificate using PHP

Tags: php, xml, pfx

I have a XML document that I want sign with a pfx certificate using PHP. How could I do this? Does some library exist or open source code, or which part of the documentation could help me! Thanks a lot for your help and excuse me for my English.

Comment: Thank you Jason!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an minimal example to sign a xml file with a pfx file:

~deleted~

Edit: Check out this libraries

- https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs
- https://github.com/selective-php/xmldsig
- https://github.com/giansalex/xmldsig
- https://github.com/Maks3w/xmldsig

Comment: I gonna put this on exercise and i confirm you, thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielO, this helps me a lot, now only gonna search how sign since a node only, thanks again